# Selecting date and assiging in proper format

Tags: angularjs

I want to select date and want to assing it to a input type my code is

```
Select Month <input type="month" id="monthYr1" ng-model="monthYr1">
```

later on in same page under same controller

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[{{$index}}].monthYr" class="form-control" value=" {{monthYr1}}"/>
```

this is assiging date to hidden field but i want date format like `MMM/YYYY`

How to achive this

Answer (score 0):

I tried following and it is working

```
Select Month 
   <input type="month" id="monthYr1" ng-model="monthYr1">

<input type="hidden" name="data[{{$index}}].monthYr" class="form-control" value=" {{monthYr1|date:'MMM/yyyy'}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use date filter :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.monthYr1 = new Date();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
<input type="text" name="data[{{$index}}].monthYr" class="form-control" value=" {{monthYr1 | date : 'MMM/YYYY'}}"/>
</div>
```